# Segfault from ld-linux in my build of glibc

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linker

Running Ubuntu 10.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux minion 2.6.32-36-generic-pae #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 8 23:25:26 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Downloaded the source and did the following:

```
CFLAGS="-O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector" '/home/user/Desktop/eglibc-2.11.1/configure' --prefix='/home/user/Desktop/eglibc_pristinebuild'
make -j4
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/tls/i686/cmov:/lib:/usr/lib
```

This works:

```
$ ./elf/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/ls /usr
bin  games  include  lib  lib64  local  sbin  share  src
```

This fails:

```
$ ./elf/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/true
Segmentation fault
```

But this works:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/true
```

`False`, `grep`, and `cat` and everything else I've tried in `/bin` segfault in the same manner.  Is there an issue with the source?  Am I compiling it incorrectly?

Also of note is that i downloaded the correct version (slightly newer) for the raspberry pi (ARM), compiled it, and it has no segfaults.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This fails:
>
> ```
> $ ./elf/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/true
> Segmentation fault
> ```

That is entirely expected outcome.

GLIBC consists of ~200 separate files, which all *must* match exactly (must have come from the same build), because they use un-versioned binary interfaces between them.

When you run `./elf/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/true`, you are using your own build of `ld-linux`, but the *system* version of `libc.so.6`, which did not come from your build.

You can confirm that that's in fact what is happening by using:

```
LD_DEBUG=files,libs ./elf/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/true
```

(this will prove that `/lib/libc.so.6` is being used).

You can fix this by using e.g.

```
./elf/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path . /bin/true
```

which will then use `./libc.so.6`

Comment: This works perfectly, but why does ls work?  It too relies heavily on libc, right?

Comment: @user2856949 "why does it work?": Both `./libc.so.6` and `./elf/ld-linux.so.2` came from the same build (*your* build), so they work together fine.

Comment: @user2856949 Ah, sorry. The reason `/bin/ls` works is most likely that it's a statically linked binary (run `ldd /bin/ls` to confirm or disprove). Another possible reason: by accident.

Comment: Nope... at least not on ubuntu:$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Comment: Also interesting:  The idea here is that the source i downloaded from apt-get is different than that used for the binary install.   I didn't think this was ever supposed to be the case.